# PDI Pentaho - Building nested XML file

Tags: xml, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

I want to build an XML file from a CSV file.

The CSV file has a structure of this kind for each row:

```
Const1
D1 (Discriminant 1)
V1
V2
.
.
.
Vn
```

The XML should have this structure:

```
<?xml....>
<Tag1>
    <Tag2>
        <Const1\>
        <D1\>
    <\Tag2>
    <BigTag1>
        <V1\>
        <Under-Tag1>
            <v1.1\>
        <\Under-Tag1>
        <Under-Tag2>
            <v1.2\>
        <\Under-Tag2>
    <\BigTag1>
<\Tag1>
```

I achieved the construction of the outer structure (heading, `Tag1`, `Tag2`) working with strings and concatenation (heading + `Tag1` + `Tag2` + `Closing Tag1`). I have problems with the nested xml, how would I achieve in Pentaho PDI the nesting of `Under-Tagn` inside `BigTagn`?

I want to at least create a different xml file for each row of csv (i.e. a file for each `Tag1`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it; I used a *Add Column XML* step, created the `<Under-Tag1>`, called for example `UT1`, then the next step of the PDI is the construction of `<BigTag1>`, where I added as a field `UT1`, as String. In the next step I used *Replace in String* and substituted `&lt;` with `<`, `&gt;` with `>`.

PDI steps:

[image: PDI]

Step `Add Column XML` BigTag1:

[image: AddXMLBT1]

Char substitution:

[image]